# Return value from column 3 when column 1 matches values in a different vector

Tags: r

I have a vector `a` with several ID codes in it:

```
a <- c(167.1, 89.7, 284.1, 108.1, 50.6, 276.5, 283.2, 357.3, 119.2, 92.2, 314.4, 400.2, 154.5, 104.5, 198.2)
> a
[1] 167.1  89.7 284.1 108.1  50.6 276.5 283.2 357.3 119.2  92.2 314.4 400.2 154.5 104.5 198.2
```

I also have data frame `y` with three columns: one being ID codes, the next being species names, and third being a biological variable (note than in my full data set, there are many lines with the same `Drop_ID` value):

```
> y[4:14,]
Drop_ID           Common.Name distance_m
4    170.4 Greenspotted Rockfish      0.389
5    167.1             Bocaccio       0.390
6    163.1 Greenspotted Rockfish      0.393
7    193.1       Copper Rockfish      0.404
8    108.1   Shortbelly Rockfish      0.405
9    114.2       Spotted Ratfish      0.405
10   190.1          Chilipepper       0.411
11   198.2          Chilipepper       0.413
12   170.4 Greenspotted Rockfish      0.423
13   119.2   Shortbelly Rockfish      0.424
14   159.2        Widow Rockfish      0.431
```

In a new vector, I want to report the values from y when the value in `y$Drop_ID` matches a value in `a` so that the end result should look like this:

```
>b
Drop_ID           Common.Name distance_m
1   167.1             Bocaccio       0.390
2   108.1   Shortbelly Rockfish      0.405
3   198.2          Chilipepper       0.413
4   119.2   Shortbelly Rockfish      0.424
```

so far the only thing I can think of to do this is a for loop with a nested if statement checking each line and if a match occurs, storing the values, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just subset it:

```
y[y$Drop_ID %in% a, ]
```